# Sum of column values ​inside Json array with group by

Tags: sql, json, django, postgresql, jsonb

I have next Django model.

```
class StocksHistory(models.Model):
    wh_data = models.JsonField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

I store JSON data in `wh_data`.

```
[
   {
      "id":4124124,
      "stocks":[
         {
            "wh":507,
            "qty":2
         },
         {
            "wh":2737,
            "qty":1
         }
      ],
   },
   {
      "id":746457457,
      "stocks":[
         {
            "wh":507,
            "qty":3
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

***Note**: it's data for one row - 2022-06-06.*

I need to calculate the sum inside stocks by grouping them by `wh` and by `created_at` so that the output is something like this

```
[
   {
      "wh":507,
      "qty":5,
      "created_at":"2022-06-06"
   },
   {
      "wh":2737,
      "qty":1,
      "created_at":"2022-06-06"
   },
      {
      "wh":507,
      "qty":0,
      "created_at":"2022-06-07"
   },
   {
      "wh":2737,
      "qty":2,
      "created_at":"2022-06-07"
   }
]
```

I know how to `group by` date, but I don't understand how to proceed with aggregations inside `JsonField`.

```
StocksHistory.objects.extra(select={'day': 'date( created_at )'})
.values('day')
.annotate(
    ???
)
```

A solution is suitable, both through `Django ORM` and through `RAW SQL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7c90e210c53bf14eb2f59bcf4b637dda)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        jsonb_path_query(js, '$[*].stocks.wh')::numeric AS wh,
        jsonb_path_query(js, '$[*].stocks.qty')::numeric AS b,
        _date
    FROM (
        VALUES ('[
   {
      "id":4124124,
      "stocks":[
         {
            "wh":507,
            "qty":2
         },
         {
            "wh":2737,
            "qty":1
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":746457457,
      "stocks":[
         {
            "wh":507,
            "qty":3
         }
      ]
   }
]'::jsonb)) v (js),
        (
            VALUES ('2022-06-06'), ('2022-06-07')) ss_ (_date)
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        wh, sum(b) AS qty,
        _date
    FROM
        cte
    GROUP BY
        1,
        3
    ORDER BY
        1
)
SELECT
    array_agg(row_to_json(cte2.*)::jsonb)
FROM
    cte2;
```

Comment: Thank you. Tell me, how can I get rid of the hardcode inside `VALUES`?

Comment: Dates can't be hardcoded. They need to be obtained from the `created_at` columns. If some date is missing, output 0.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you refer the first array object to `2022-06-06` and the second to `2022-06-07`?

This is not entirely correct, because I just gave an example of objects array that applies to `2022-06-06`.

Comment: @unknown You need to supply date information to the query.VALUES is one way to construct the date values. another way to use select to supply the date values.

Comment: Thnx. Can you edit your answer for testing?

Comment: @unknown I added a new demo link. Hope that will help you. \

Comment: Wow. This is amazing.

I have another question:
If I also need to add an aggregation to the output by another field from this table, for example, the `name` field - do I need to create `cte3`? how then to add `sum(b) by name` to the result?

If needed, I can create a separate question for this.